# DC motor slows down after running for a few seconds

Tags: motor, dc

My DC motor slows down after running fast for around 20 seconds. I added a second 9 v battery in series but same problem. 
Nothing is printed on motor so I don't know it's voltage range.
The load also doesn't vary (I think so) as it's only spinning a fan.
The motor itself doesn't heat up, though batteries are getting a bit hot. 
I have nothing between batteries and the motor. Are the batteries not grunty enough for the motor? Should I place the batteries in parallel for cooler operation? Should I experiment with lower battery voltages?
Unfortunately I don't have a multimeter so can't test anything.

Might be a silly question as I  am a newbie with electrical/electronic stuff, but please do answer as I am not getting much with searching!!

Comment: The batteries are getting hot, that's your clue. Get a multimeter.

Comment: For a more likely solution, first show a picture of the fan and where it's from  or similar https://www.google.ca/search?q=dc+fan&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X  Do you have any idea how many different incompatible fans there are?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly likely that the growth of internal resistance in your battery due to an excessive load is the problem. Standard 9 volt batteries are pretty poor (generalism alert) at powering DC motors. If you had a multimeter there is a very good chance that you would see the battery voltage progressively lower the longer you had the motor connected.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Can you suggest an alternative to the standard 9 v battery? Is it to do with diff battery brands or there is something on the battery ratings that I should be seeing? Or I should have a voltage regulator (potentiometer?) ?

Comment: Most 9 volt PP3 style batteries are just not equipped to provide circa 1 amp of current and will rapidly produce poor performance when connected to a motor. Without knowing the ratings for your motor it's impossible to say what would be better. Having a voltage regulator just puts off the point where discharge effects becomes obvious AND because a lower voltage is produced by a regulator the initial speed of the motor will be significantly reduced.

Comment: 9V batteries are made with very tiny cells, so can only deliver low currents.  A set of 6 AA cells connected in series will produce 9 volts, but can deliver a much higher current than a pp3 battery.  A set of C or D cells would be much better than AA cells.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line here is that you need to get a multimeter so that you can perform testing. This is the best way to collect real data that contributes to real learning so you can proceed beyond having to say that you are a newbie.

If you were able to deploy a meter you would most likely see that the battery voltage diminishes a fairly large amount after the motor load has been attached.

The meter would also allow you to measure current flow in the circuit to help access if the load requirements of the motor are outside of the realistic current supply capacity of the battery.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the quick response. I will get a multimeter and do the testing.

Answer (score 0):

Place a compass near one (ONE) of the wires. You will see some deflection of the needle, initially. You may need to move the compass around, to get best deflection, or plan ahead about orientation between wire and compass and NORTH.

Then, rapidly, you will see the compass needle deflect less, because the current drops.

Your own multi-meter. You can increase the sensitivity by wrapping a few turns of wire (insulated) right around the compass; leave some gaps so you can still see the needle.

Comment: Compasses make poor multimeters. If you're stuck on a desert island ... well if you had a compass, you probably wouldn't end up stuck on a desert island.